# Webpack shows warning when I import React Router

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

```
(webpack)/buildin/global.js
[1] There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
[1] This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
[1] Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
[1] * E:\Code-maniac\MERN\SOCIALIZE\client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!E:\Code-maniac\MERN\SOCIALIZE\client\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
[1]     Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
[1]     E:\Code-maniac\MERN\SOCIALIZE\client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!E:\Code-maniac\MERN\SOCIALIZE\client\node_modules\node-libs-browser\node_modules\punycode\punycode.js
[1] * E:\Code-maniac\MERN\SOCIALIZE\client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!E:\Code-maniac\MERN\socialize\client\node_modules\webpack\buildin\global.js
[1]     Used by 2 module(s), i. e.
[1]     E:\Code-maniac\MERN\SOCIALIZE\client\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--6-oneOf-2!E:\Code-maniac\MERN\socialize\client\node_modules\symbol-observable\es\index.js
```

When I try to import:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

I see the above warnings. What could be the reason? I am using create-react-app

Comment: _[1] There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing._...check this. Have you imported some modules with different casing?

Comment: I've checked that.

Comment: @Jai If I remove that imports line then it doesn't shows any warning.

Comment: Can you maybe reproduce the error in a code sandbox

Comment: This is happening with me too. With React 16.13.1 and React Router 5.2.0.